# Typescript - Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[any?, ...any[]]'

Tags: typescript

It is basically a warning, but how can I address it?

`main.ts:8:71 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[any?, ...any[]]'`

When I override the tsconfig file with a flag `-t 'ES2019'` there are no errors but when I use the tsconfig file, because the `noImplicitAny` is set to true it (obviously) complains (but still creates the js file).

I am not sure what the correct approach is in the code that will allow `noImplicitAny to be set

Comment: I am about 80% sure I once read a GH issue about this ..

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] we can look at?  You can likely [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) your way out of whatever problem you're having, but it would be nice to see something concrete so I can make suggestions.  Good luck!

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir It's not exactly [#29311](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29311)... still looking

Comment: @jcalz I might be misremembering. I probably confused it with [#29311](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29311)